# Problem with handling a factor of $1$ in pattern matching

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching

I am trying to implement the creation and annihilation operators $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ of quantum mechanics with the following code, but alas, there is a problem with the pattern matching for the leading coefficient $cc\_$. Any idea on how to fix this? I tried $cc\_:1$, but that didn't work.

```
Clear[a, adag, cc, ketk, nn]; (* Choosing nn and cc to avoid name collisions *)
a[cc_ ketk_Ket] := With[{nn = ketk[[1]]}, cc Sqrt[nn] Ket[nn - 1]];
adag[cc_ ketk_Ket] := With[{nn = ketk[[1]]}, cc Sqrt[nn + 1] Ket[nn + 1]];
```

When I try give `Ket[0]`, i.e., $3|1\rangle$, to `adag`, I get back `adag[Ket[0]]`, but if there is a leading coefficient, then the pattern match works. For example, `adag[3 Ket[0]]` returns `3 Ket[1]`, i.e., $3|1\rangle$ . I think this shows my code doesn't know what to do for the first case in terms of matching.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When in doubt about the interpretation of a pattern (especially involving operations such as `Times` with special `Attributes`), it's best to specify the desired pattern in [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullForm.html) instead of [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StandardForm.html), because it removes ambiguities.

For your case, the desired `FullForm` version with the optional argument for the scalar factor would be

```
Clear[a, adag, cc, ketk, nn];(*Choosing nn and cc to avoid name collisions*)
a[Times[cc_: 1, ketk_Ket]] := 
 With[{nn = ketk[[1]]}, cc Sqrt[nn] Ket[nn - 1]];
adag[Times[cc_ : 1, ketk_Ket]] := 
  With[{nn = ketk[[1]]}, cc Sqrt[nn + 1] Ket[nn + 1]];
```

Now you get the expected results:

```
adag[Ket[0]]

(* ==> Ket[1] *)

adag[2 Ket[0]]

(* ==> 2 Ket[1] *)
```

By using `Times` explicitly, I make sure that *Mathematica* knows what part of the expression is to be parsed as the option value. If you don't do this, the expression is misunderstood:

```
FullForm[g[cc_: 1 ketk_Ket]]
```

> `g[Optional[Pattern[cc,Blank[]],Pattern[ketk,Blank[Ket]]]]`

What happened here is that the `Optional` value was taken to be `1 ketk_Ket` which evaluates to `ketk_Ket`. That's of course not what you wanted, it's just a consequence of operator precedence here. You could also have fixed this by using parentheses in the `StandardForm` pattern you tried originally, but using `FullForm` is usually clearer.

In some cases one also has to protect the pattern from simplifying by using [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldPattern.html), but that's not needed in this application.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helps!

Answer (score 4):

May be (if I understand you correctly) you can add a default value for arguments:

```
Default[a] = 1;
Default[adag] = 1;
```

and then change the functions argument in the definition to:

```
a[cc_. ketk_Ket] :=....
adag[cc_. ketk_Ket] :=....
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be noted that follow forms of definition will work.

```
a[(cc_:1) ketk_Ket] := With[{nn = ketk[[1]]}, cc Sqrt[nn] Ket[nn - 1]]
```

[image: a-ket]

```
adag[(cc_:1) ketk_Ket] := With[{nn = ketk[[1]]}, cc Sqrt[nn + 1] Ket[nn + 1]]
```

[image: adag-ket]

Answer (score 2):

Does Mathematica support `Polymorphism` ? Yes, at least `function overloading`it does.
I have stripped your methods a bit,

```
adag[cc_ ketk_Ket] := With[{nn = ketk}, {cc, nn} ]    
adag[ketk_Ket] := With[{nn = ketk, cc = 1}, {cc, ketk} ]
```

Usage:

```
adag[Ket[3]] => {1, Ket[3]}
adag[2*Ket[4]] => {2, Ket[4]}
```

Or you can use default arguments as suggested above. But its helpful in scenarios where overloading cannot be escaped.